# How to do ordering the test cases using @pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Guys help me out of this problem .. I want to order test cases using annotation

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.run(order=2)
```

but it's not working, I installed using command `pip install pytest` 
tell me guys how to solve this problem or else give me some alternative solution

Comment: please update with the relevant source code for your tests, what do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is not from `pytest`, but from the plugin [pytest-ordering](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering), which you can install with `pip install pytest-ordering`

Comment: Hi .. I already installed "pip install pytest-ordering" -- after "mark" -- run(order =1) it's not taking

Comment: what do you mean by -- after "mark" -- run(order =1)